# Can I use the same Git repo after upgrading my project from VS2017 to VS2022?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, repository, repo

Can I use the same Git repo after upgrading my project from VS2017 to VS2022? Or is it better to create a new repo for the upgraded project?

Thank you.

Couldn't find any solutions online. Helps would be much appreciated.

Comment: It should be fine...... even though I do not use VS so can't really tell... it's an educated guess, say.

Answer (score 2):

Git repos shouldn't depend on developer tools, just the code. So if you upgrade your VS version, your project should remain the same.

If you have configuration files or dependencies from Visual Studio you want to keep, you can keep them in the same repo and if one day you have to rollback your version, you can always check your commit history or navigate to a previous commit.